# api level 8 HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, android

this is my first post - so I hope did everything right concerning code-formatting.

Maybe you can help me with the following problem:

With API-Level 10 and above, all my HttpURLConnections are working fine, but with API-Level 8 some (or sometimes most) of my attempts to download the content of a file (txt, html…) fails.

I worked around this by just repeating the download whenever the server returned the response code “-1”.  This is not very satisfying but it works (more or less) – but I guess it only works because of the fact that the content I receive is very short (max 100 chars) – and sometimes I think some chars at the end were omitted, too.

But now I tried to implement an update routine (downloading and installing an apk-File) which most of the times fails, because the apk file is fragmented (I guess), so I get a “Parsing error” when trying to install the file.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you for any help (and staying friendly if you are better than me *g*)!

Here’s the code of my update routine (which – as you can see – has no repeating mechanism as described above):

```java
    String download_url  = "http://url/";
    String download_file = "name.apk";

    //Local
    String update_file = download_file;
    File update_file_stream = context.getFileStreamPath(update_file);

    //Connect
    URL url = new URL(download_url + download_file);
    HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    c.setRequestMethod("GET");
    c.setDoOutput(true);
    c.connect();

    //Delete local File?
    if(update_file_stream.exists()){

        update_file_stream.delete();
    }

    //Download File
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(update_file, Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    InputStream is = c.getInputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int len1 = 0;
    while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, len1);
    }
    fos.close();
    is.close();

    //Install
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(update_file_stream), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like Network on Main Thread issue.

In the previous android sdk version (maybe 8) you can do some network on Main Thread

but after ICS or Honeycomb you can't do any network stuff on Main Thread.

Comment: Hi... thank you for your answer! I know about this issue, but all network activity is being executed either in "protected Void doInBackground(String... arg0) {}" or in "new AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>() {}". So this does not seem to cause the problem.